# How to capture the pop-up window while automating web app.?

Tags: ruby, selenium

I'm using ruby, but my script is unable to capture pop-up window. I tried in many ways but no use. Some of them are here

---

1.

```
@selenium.wait_for_pop_up "_blank","30000"
@selenium.select_window "_blank"
```

---

2.

```
@selenium.window_focus "window title"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can get the total list of window titles and select the desired one. Hope you understand the java code below

```
    String wndwTitles[] = sel.getAllWindowTitles();
    sel.selectWindow(wndwTitles[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

When using capybara, you can do the following:

```
driver = Capybara::Driver::Selenium.driver

# driver.window_handles returns a list of all current windows,
# just select the one you are interested in
window = driver.window_handles.detect {|w| ... }

driver.switch_to.window(window) do
  # do whatever you want with the selected window...
end
```

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

**To Handle pop-up windows** *Ruby - Selenium WebDriver*

```
@driver.window_handles    
@driver.switch_to.window @driver.window_handles.<first/last>
```

first - parent window(To switch back from pop-up window)
last - child window(Switch to pop-up)